# Missing partition / drive Centos 7

Tags: linux, partition, sudo, ntfs, uuid

I was trying to change permissions on one of my NTFS partitions and I think I have messed something up. I entered the below command on Centos 7 and now the partition is missing from the File Manager. How do I undo this?

```
  sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000,exec /dev/sdf2
```

Some info.

```
[root@localhost james]# sudo sfdisk -l -uM
    Disk /dev/sdf: 972801 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
    sfdisk: Warning: The partition table looks like it was made
      for C/H/S=*/256/63 (instead of 972801/255/63).
    For this listing I'll assume that geometry.

    Units: 1MiB = 1024*1024 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

       Device Boot Start   End    MiB    #blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdf1         0+ 2097151  2097152- 2147483647+  ee  GPT
    /dev/sdf2         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
    /dev/sdf3         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
    /dev/sdf4         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
```

Also when I look at the drive on gparted, I can see the 4 partitions, however the label is blank for sdf2.

[image]

I think this has something to do with a missing UUID and Label

```
[root@localhost dev]# sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdf2 MEDIA
Error getting information about /dev/sdf2: Input/output error

[root@localhost dev]# tune2fs /dev/sdf2 -U 8E5473C95473B317
tune2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
tune2fs: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sdf2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Not even sure im doing this right. Hope the data is not lost

Please let me know if you need other output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed!.

Steps taken

1.

```
root@localhost james]# umount  -v /dev/sdf2
umount: /run/media/james (/dev/sdf2) unmounted
```

2.

```
cd /run/media/james
```

3.

`mkdir MEDIA`

4.

```
vi /etc/fstab
```

5.

Edited fstab with

```
/dev/sdf2             /run/media/james/MEDIA    ntfs-3g   defaults  0 0
```

6.

```
mount  /dev/sdf2
```

Big thanks to the CENTOS [community](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=57307)!